# Fixed-width elements that wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of thumbnails that I wish to display in my page. The widths of the thumbnails are not necessarily all the same, and neither are the heights. What I'd like to do is arrange them in a tabular format such that elements line up in neat rows and columns with each "cell" being an equal, specified width.

I do not want to use a table as I would like the number of rows/columns to automatically re-size with a browser re-size.

I've tried sticking the images in:

1. `div`s of `fixed-width` with `float` left. The problem is because of unequal heights, wrapped `div`s might "catch" on the bottom of a `div` on the row above.
2. `span`s and `li`s: setting `width: 200px` or whatever doesn't seem to fix the width; however they do wrap fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `display: inline-block` on your spans or lis, that should allow you to set the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/bnmPR/

Comment: Thanks. I thought this had pretty weak x-browser support though?

Comment: I was too slow, but I made a fiddle so I may as well post it:  http://jsfiddle.net/y7tPa/1/

Comment: As for browser support, depending on version and doc-type, IE has trouble with it.  As long as you use it on an element which is originally inline (span) then it's fine.  Don't use it on a div or certain versions of IE will ignore it.

Comment: @Richard - IE supports inline-block from IE 5.5 on, with one caveat - it only knows how to do it for inline elements.  We're working with `<span>`, so no problem here.  As of IE 8, inline-block is fully supported.  IE 7 is [quickly becoming irrelevant](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-weekly-201129-201129-bar).

Comment: Also, you can get IE 7 (and 6 and 5.5) to work on block elements by first setting the display to inline-block, and then in a new declaration, set it to inline.  Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bnmPR/2/.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `li`s and make them `display:inline-block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zDC2w/

Drag the window over to see it work.

*borders, width, and height added to show effect*

Comment: Pretty good according to Quirksmode: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html  And here's how you make IE7 behave.  Scroll down: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display

Answer (score 0):

you can still use you divs that float left and add this script: http://masonry.desandro.com/

It will push the divs up vertically so that they are beside each other.